# mimic kernel's response to a program that network is not connected?

Tags: networking, iptables, command-line-interface, kernel

First let's block all incoming / outgoing traffic.

> vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Next: let's test **ping**

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

at that point ping **stalls**.. perhaps will wait until times out.

Now let's disconnect the network interface and try again:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

beautiful, it stopped instantly. ( no stalling or waiting for time out )

Some recommended using "**REJECT**" in the iptables-rules
and even play with the **-j REJECT --reject-with** flags..

I have tried them all.
there is no way to send the **same signal the kernel

is sending** to the program when the **network interface is disconnected**.
( via iptables )

This is what I want to do for now:

> figure a way to ensure **Kernel** tells **ping** that **network is
>   disconnected**. 
>   ( or run a command in another terminal manually to send such a signal )

this way ping will not stall. it will simply say

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

and stop.

Can it be done & how ?

Comment: Once you've earned sufficient rep points, you can come and state your case on meta.SF as to why you think this line of questioning is on-topic here. Question comments are not a place to discuss topicality.

Comment: The SF community sets its own expectations on question topicality. We are willing to hear your point of view, but at the same time, we expect people to spend some time getting to know how things work here before complaining. Please step back and take a deep breath. None of this is personal. Your question is not bad. It's just off-topic here. You may consider that insulting those which are trying to help you is not a great way to get help.